# Getting error while setting up pod

Tags: ios, iphone, git, cocoapods

Previously I am getting another error to resolve that I removed master repo and after that trying to install pods and I am getting below error. I checked other options also but they are not working for me.

```
Mys-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ pod setup
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --depth=1
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see `man xcode-select`)
```

please let me know what to do here.

Comment: Did you install Xcode?

Comment: Yes, I did Xcode 7.2